# Does archname directory get scanned automatically?

Tags: perl

When I want to provide directory to include modules I write:

```
perl -Ilib -Isome/dir script.pl
```

Should I include `archname` directory too or is that scanned automatically?

from `Makefile`:

```
{APP_ROOT}/local/lib/perl5/${shell perl -MConfig -e 'print $$Config{archname}'}
```

**UPD**

`perl -V` output:

```
/home/kes/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.24.0/lib/site_perl/5.24.0/x86_64-linux
/home/kes/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.24.0/lib/site_perl/5.24.0
/home/kes/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.24.0/lib/5.24.0/x86_64-linux
/home/kes/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.24.0/lib/5.24.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`archname` is included in `@INC` by default if it exists:

```
perl -MConfig -E 'say $_ for ($Config{archname}, @INC)'
x86_64-linux
/home/user/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.24.1/lib/site_perl/5.24.1/x86_64-linux
/home/user/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.24.1/lib/site_perl/5.24.1
/home/user/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.24.1/lib/5.24.1/x86_64-linux
/home/user/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.24.1/lib/5.24.1
```

**UPD**
It will be added if it exists:

`perl -Isomedir -e 'local $"="\n"; print "@INC"'`

```
somedir
/home/kes/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.24.0/lib/site_perl/5.24.0/x86_64-linux
/home/kes/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.24.0/lib/site_perl/5.24.0
/home/kes/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.24.0/lib/5.24.0/x86_64-linux
/home/kes/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.24.0/lib/5.24.0
```

`mkdir -p somedir/x86_64-linux`
`perl -Isomedir -e 'local $"="\n"; print "@INC"'`

```
somedir/x86_64-linux
somedir
/home/kes/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.24.0/lib/site_perl/5.24.0/x86_64-linux
/home/kes/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.24.0/lib/site_perl/5.24.0
/home/kes/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.24.0/lib/5.24.0/x86_64-linux
/home/kes/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.24.0/lib/5.24.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, **if it exists**, the arch sub directory will be added to `@INC` when you add the parent non-arch directory.

Baseline:

```
$ perl -E'say for @INC' | wc -l
5
```

Add via `-I`:

```
$ perl -Ilib -E'say for @INC' | head -n -5
lib/5.24.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
lib/5.24.0
lib
```

Add via `PERL5LIB`:

```
$ PERL5LIB=lib perl -E'say for @INC' | head -n -5
lib/5.24.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
lib/5.24.0
lib
```

Add via lib.pm:

```
$ perl -E'use lib qw( lib ); say for @INC' | head -n -5
lib/5.24.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
lib/5.24.0
lib
```

Add via mylib.pm:

```
$ perl -E'use mylib; say for @INC' | head -n -5
/.../lib/5.24.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/.../lib/5.24.0
/.../lib
```

It **doesn't** add them if you add directly to `@INC`:

```
$ perl -E'unshift @INC, "lib"; say for @INC' | head -n -5
lib
```

Comment: It's important to try each method because it's up to each of them to add the arch dir themselves (because `@INC` is not magical in that respect). `-I` and `PERL5LIB` probably use the same mechanism. lib.pm uses its own. mylib.pm uses lib.pm.